# != null vs. =null

Tags: c#, .net, null

See below code first please.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            public List<MyStructItem> Items;
        }
        public struct MyStructItem
        {
            public string Value;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyStruct> myList = new List<MyStruct>();
            myList.Add(new MyStruct());

            //(!) it haven't comipled.
            if (myList[0].Items = null){Console.WriteLine("null!");}

            //(!) but it have compiled.
            if (myList[0].Items != null) { Console.WriteLine("not null!"); }

        }
    }
}
```

What is difference between `!=null` and `=null` in that case?

thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`.

Try:

```
//(!) it haven't comipled.            
if (myList[0].Items == null){Console.WriteLine("null!");}            

//(!) but it have compiled.            
if (myList[0].Items != null) { Console.WriteLine("not null!"); }
```

The difference is one compiles and one doesn't :-)

C# Operators:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Why does the compiler not compile 'myList[0].Items = null'? Is myList readonly?

Comment: Having thought about it for another minute or so, I guess the answer to my own question is that the problem is that the C# compiler won't automatically convert an object to a bool. As an old C/C++ hand I keep forgetting how different C# is!

Comment: @AAT it will complain that it can't convert it to a bool.  `myList[0].Items = null` on its own will compile.

Answer (score 5):

`= null` is **assignment**. You should use `== null`

You assign the `null` value to `myList[0].Items` and tries to use it as bool in `if` statement. That is why code can not be compiled.
For example, this code compiles successfully:

```
bool b;
if (b = true)
{
    ...
}
```

Because you set `true` value to `b` and then check it in `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

`=null` you set the value to null

`!= null` you check if it is different from null

If you want to compare if it is equal to null, `use == null` instead of = null.

Answer (score 3):

'=' is for assignment, not for comparing. Use '=='

Answer (score 2):

```
if (myList[0].Items == null){Console.WriteLine("null!");}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, `myList[0].Items = null` will set the object to null. You probably mean `myList[0].Items == null`

And regarding the difference, == checked if something is equal. != checks if something is not equal.

Answer (score 1):

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (`==`) returns true if
>   the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference
>   types other than string, `==` returns true if its two operands refer to
>   the same object. For the string type, `==` compares the values of the
>   strings.

And

> The assignment operator (`=`) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand and returns the value as its result. The operands must be of
>   the same type (or the right-hand operand must be implicitly
>   convertible to the type of the left-hand operand).

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator, you should use the equality operator `==`

Answer (score 1):

`= null` is an assignment. `== null` is a condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myList[0].Items != null)
```

is a **negative comparison**. It checks if `myList[0].Items` is **not** equal to `null`.

```
if (myList[0].Items = null)
```

is an assignment. It would normally assign `null` to `myList[0].Items` and return true (in languages like C++), however, in C#, this won't compile (because of this common error).